# NodeJs crawler for recipes

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js, web-scraping, ecmascript-8

Here is my try on a crawler made in nodeJs with [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), I made it with the idea in mind to use it in a future project I wanna make. Here is the git link: [https://github.com/Just4lol/CookCrawler](https://github.com/Just4lol/CookCrawler/tree/f64f90568be9b022c354cf3ee7774eb4b448738a)

If you look at the **index.js** you will see how to use it;

```js
const cookCrawler = require('./cookCrawler.js')

cookCrawler.getRecipeData(recipeUrl).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

I think this part is ok (will still take your feedback :) ), my problem is with the structure behind. For each website that I want to parse the data from, I need to create a new parser script so to try to save some code duplication and add structure to the project I created the **RecipeParser** class which they extend.

```js
class RecipeParser {
    async loadHtml(url) {
        this.recipeUrl = url;

        try {
            const recipeHtml = await requestP(url);
            // Load the virtual DOM 
            this.$ = cheerio.load(recipeHtml);

            return this;
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    async parseHtml(url) {
        try {
            await this.loadHtml(url)
            return this.parse()
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    getTitle(selector) {
        return this.whiteSpaceRemover(this.$(selector).text())
    }

    getRecipeInfo(selector) {        
        throw new Error('You have to implement the method getRecipeInfo!');
    }

    getIngredients(selector) {

        throw new Error('You have to implement the method getIngredients!');
    }

    getSteps(selector) {
        throw new Error('You have to implement the method getSteps!');
    }

    getRecipeImgUrl(selector) {
        return this.$(selector).attr('href')   
    }

    /**
     * Return the obj
     */
    parse() {
        return {
            recipeUrl: this.recipeUrl,
            title: this.getTitle(),
            recipeInfo: this.getRecipeInfo(),
            ingredients: this.getIngredients(),
            steps: this.getSteps(),
            recipeImgUrl: this.getRecipeImgUrl()
        }
    }

    getTxtArrayFromElements(selector) {
        const array = []
        this.$(selector).each((i, element) => {
            array.push(this.$(element).text())
        })

        return array
    }

    whiteSpaceRemover(string) {
        return string.replace(whiteSpaceRemReg, '')
    }
}

module.exports = RecipeParser
```

It does its job but is not very scalable if I want to add additional properties and in general, I'm not really happy with it and I'm sure there is a better way of doing it. I liked the idea of mixin but, I may be wrong, but I don't think it would be helpful in my case because each website is too unique and one logic from one cannot really apply to another. Here the function from ricardoParse.js to extract the ingredients from one of their recipes

```js
getIngredients() {
        // If the form have h3 in it, that mean the recipe have 2 recipe in it
        if(this.$('#formIngredients > h3').length) {
            let obj = {}
            // for each recipe title link the array of ingredients to it 
            this.$('#formIngredients > h3').each((i, element) => {
                    obj[this.$(element).text()] = (() => {
                        const ingredients = []
                        this.$(this.$('#formIngredients > ul ')[i]).find('li').each((j, ulElement) => {
                            ingredients.push(this.whiteSpaceRemover(this.$(ulElement).text()))
                        })

                        return ingredients
                })()
            })

            return obj
        } 
        else return this.getTxtArrayFromElements('#formIngredients ul > li > label > span')
    }
```

The last thing is the "factory" im using would be a real pain if I have more than 10 parser in it;

```js
class CookCrawler  {
    static getRecipeData(url) {
        const domain = url.match(domainMatchReg).toString()
        switch(domain) {
            case 'https://www.ricardocuisine.com':
                const ricardoParser = new RicardoParser()

                return ricardoParser.parseHtml(url)
            case 'https://www.troisfoisparjour.com':
                const troisfoisparjourParse = new TroisfoisparjourParser()

                return troisfoisparjourParse.parseHtml(url)
            default: 
                console.warn('No parser exist for ths domain or wrong url.')
                break
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I make it more scalable and maintainable**, and I have done a good job?

Answer (score 1):

> I think this part is ok (will still take your feedback :) )

`RecipeParser::parseHtml` is asynchronous - `CookCrawler::getRecipeData()` could also be asynchronous as well.

As far as the "factory" method is concerned, a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or simple Object could be used to store the mappings of domains to the parsers. Then instead of using a `switch` statement, have the code check to see if the mapping contains the domain and utilize the associated parser class.

---

`getTxtArrayFromElements()` contains this block:

> ```
>     const array = []
>     this.$(selector).each((i, element) => {
>         array.push(this.$(element).text())
>     })
>
>    return array
> ```

Whenever there is a (for)each loop that pushes data into an array, consider if a [*map*-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method is available. Cheerio has [`.map()`](https://cheerio.js.org/#map-functionindex-element-), similar to jQuery's [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map). That can be used to avoid manually setting up the array and pushing items into it.

The same would likely apply to `ingredients` in that `getIngredients()` method.